# Legal permissions required to host foreign guests in India via Airbnb

Tags: legal, india, airbnb, mumbai

I heard that we need to register a paying foreign guest with the nearest police station, is this necessary and true? Also what is the procedure to obtain them for Mumbai India?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Airbnb as well, check how they feel about this? Given that they would have ran in to this in other countries as well

Comment: Is there a [tourism tax](https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/481) that might be required irrespective of hosting a foreign guest or a domestic guest?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legalities of running an AirBnB site.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to fill out [Form C](http://boi.gov.in/content/form-c) online for every guest.